# section position: fixed overlaps footer

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to css and html.
The issue is pretty simple, but I'm stack..

I have a `<section>` tag with `position:fixed` that remains fixed when I scroll down the page.

But this section overlaps the footer at the end and I don't want it to happen.
Here the code:

```
<!-- section tag -->
    <section class="fix">
            <header>
                <h2>Corsi</h2>
            </header>
            <div class="row">
                <section class="6u">
                    <ul class="default">
                        <li><a href="#">softwares</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">others</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
    </section>

<!.. css of the class -->
    .fix
    {
    position: fixed;
    }
```

and here the footer content and related css:

```
<!-- html of the footer -->
<div id="footer">
    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="6u">
                <header>
                    <h2>Social</h2>
                </header>
                <ul class="footer">
                    <li><span class="white"><span class="phone"></span></span>li>
                </ul>
            </section>
    </section>
</div>

<!-- css of the footer -->
    #footer
    {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #footer header h2
    {
        color: #FFF !important;
    }

    #footer header .byline
    {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
```

Comment: For us to be able to help properly, you need to post a working code piece where no relevant html/css is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `z-index` property:

```
.fix {position: fixed;z-index: 1;}
#footer {position: relative;z-index: 9999;background:#ffffff;}
```

EDIT: Also set a background color to the footer, so it won't be transparent

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work.. I have another ``z-index: 100`` for the ``navbar`` but it should not disturb..

Comment: @matteo - Try setting `background:#ffffff;` to **#footer** (I edited the answer)

Comment: thanks.. ok adding the ``background-color`` works.. and I don't have to add the ``z-index`` value.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have couple of issues in your html code. Several closing tags are missed or misplaced.

```
<!-- section tag -->
<section class="fix">
        <header>
            <h2>Corsi</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="6u">
                <ul class="default">
                    <li><a href="#">softwares</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">others</a></li>
                </ul>
            </section>
    </div>
</section>


<div id="footer">
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <section class="6u">
            <header>
                <h2>Social</h2>
            </header>
            <ul class="footer">
                <li><span class="white"><span class="phone"></span></span></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        </div>
</section>
```

You do not need z-index since you have not declared any position for the footer. See the working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zero_point/z6xsmxxa/)

Comment: thanks for the code.. but I'm not able to make it working.. I'll keep trying

Comment: it might be something else in your page. could you please create the webpage in JSFIDDLE.NET so that we can see the entire HTML and CSS codes?